# Slide shape along path in Python?

Tags: python, polygons, shapely

I'd like to slide an arbitrary polygon along a path and return the shape of the outline of the polygon over the entire path. For example, in the below picture I want the blue polygon to slide along the red path, yielding the green polygon:

[image: circle slid along path]

The Shapely package has quite a few useful functions, but not this one exactly. 
The buffer function doesn't handle arbitrary shapes, it just expands circularly.

I could make fine points along the path, create copies of the circle at each point, then do a cascaded union, but that would be very slow and the edges would have many points that would need to be simplified.

Another option is to create rectangles out of each line segment in the circle being slid over each line segment of the path, then get the cascaded union of those. This too may be inefficient.

I'm sure someone's probably done this problem type before. **Is there an already existing Python package that can get this done, or an easy and efficient solution that I haven't considered?**

Here's a code snippet to start with:

```
from shapely.geometry import Point, LineString
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot
from matplotlib.patches import Polygon
from matplotlib.collections import PatchCollection

def plot_coords(ax, ob):
    x, y = ob.xy
    ax.plot(x, y, 'o', color='#000000', zorder=1)

def plot_line(ax, ob):
    x, y = ob.xy
    ax.plot(x, y, color='#FF2222', alpha=0.7, linewidth=3, solid_capstyle='round', zorder=2)

circle = Point([-2,0]).buffer(1.0, 4)
path = LineString([[0,0],[1,1],[2,-1]])

fig = pyplot.figure(1, figsize=(12,10), dpi=180)
ax = fig.add_subplot(121)
plot_coords(ax, path)
plot_line(ax, path)
polygon_patch = Polygon(circle.exterior.coords, True)
p = PatchCollection([polygon_patch], cmap=matplotlib.cm.jet, alpha=0.4)
ax.add_collection(p)

plot_coords(ax, circle.exterior)


ax.set_xlim(-4, 3)
ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
ax.set_aspect(1)

pyplot.show()
```

[image: python code output]

Comment: very, very interesting question. I think it is not completely specified though. If you want not to use circles, I infer the polygon should not be rotated during the sliding, but what is the point you should use to make the slide over the line? the center of mass of the polygon? the upper point?

Comment: That's true. I imagine a single (x,y) reference point would probably have to be specified for a general case.

Answer (score 0):

I had this come up recently and the solution I ended up with was to union the collection of convex-hulls that are formed by the "sliding polygon" considered along the path vertices. This only works if the "sliding polygon" is itself convex but that's probably common -- but not exactly the OP's question. As the OP stated, in the case of a circular "sliding polygon" the .buffer() will work.